# Удалить слово с запятой Javascript

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Добрый день! Пожалуйста, подскажите как должно выглядеть ругулярное выражение на JS для того, чтобы удалить слово с принадлежащей запятой?

Например, есть строка:

```
11, 22, 33, 44, 55
```

Если решил удалить 11, то получилось

```
22, 33, 44, 55
```

Если 55, то:

```
11, 22, 33, 44
```

Чтобы запятая не терялась и не было лишних запятых. 
Спасибо!

Comment: Слова могут быть как с запятыми, так и без?

    ааа, я б ввв, ддд, у ллл

Comment: @sergiks

вы написали "а я б вдул"?

Comment: @Spectre: шутка не прошла. Вечно хэш с лепрой путаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так будет быстрее и надежнее чем регекспом:

```
function rem_word(text, word) {
    return text.split(', ') //делим - ', '
        .filter(function (e) {
        return e != word; //удаляем ненужные слова
    }).join(', '); //клеим
}
console.log(rem_word('11, 22, 33, 44, 55',11));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/esMeT/

Если нужен регексп, то вот так:

```
function rem_word2(text,word) {
   var reg=new RegExp(word+',\\s+|,\\s+'+word,'g');
   return text.replace(reg,'');
}
```

В этом случае правда косяк может быть с со строкой типа '55, 44, 33, 111' и попыткой удаления 11 либо 4, в общем лучше `split`, если пробел может быть не один, то из комментариев пример возьмите.

Comment: ... если количество пробелов постоянно.

Comment: это к вопросу о качестве данных, и еще вот так можно сделать, при необходимости http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/esMeT/2/ или так http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/esMeT/3/

Comment: Очень благодарен, количество должно быть постоянным, я нашаманил до этого при помощи indexOf, теперь склоняюсь больше к функции rem_word. Спасибо еще раз!

Answer (score 4):

Например, [так](http://jsfiddle.net/8bbeu/1/):

```
var s = "11, 22, 33, 44, 55, lalala, fafafa";
var parts = s.split(/,\s*/g);
var indexToRemove = 0;
parts.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
s = parts.join(", ");
```

(говорят, может не сработать в IE, тестируйте)

Comment: а зачем сплит с пробелами? просто сплит по запятой, вы же удаляете по индексу.

    var parts = s.split(','); 
    parts.splice(index,1); 
    s = parts.join(',');

Comment: @Yura Ivanov: для эстетики, чтобы после прохода функции везде был ровно один пробел.

Comment: ну, для эстетики вообще пробелы не нужны. просто вы удаляете произвольное число пробелов, а вставляете только один, т.е. производите не просто удаление, а еще и меняете остальную строку. если они нужны эти пробелы, то возможно они нужны все...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov: если у нас настоящие comma-separated values, значимые пробелы надо бы заключать в кавычки (тогда парсер будет сложнее). В любом случае, что конкретно лучше подходит к задаче пусть решает ТС.

Comment: согласен, ТС решает сам. Я не то, чтобы придрался, просто заметил, что такое преобразование лишнее в плане изменения входных данных без необходимости...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov: на самом деле, непонятно, убирать ли вместе со словом _следующую_ запятую и возможные пробелы перед ней (и после неё?), или _предыдущую_ и пробелы после неё (и перед ней?). В принципе, варианты симметричны.

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

```
function numReplace(text, num) {
    return text.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+num+"\\s*,\\s*(?=\\S)|\\b,\\s*"+num+"\\s*$|^\\s*"+num+"\\s*$", "g"), "");
};
```

Все, конечный вариант (уже раз десятый коммент правлю).